# Unknown element exceeds the window

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have the following problem: in my web page when I reduce the size of the window, a horizontal scrollbar appears below as if I would had content that exceed the size of the window. But when I took a look at it I can't identify the problem: isn't the navbar (that is "fixed") and neither one of the elements of the sponsors that is floated. I have deleted both of them and the problem persists.

I'm pasting a link to the webpage and I would be very grateful if anyone could help me. If anyone need some of the HTML or CSS code please ask me and I will provide it.

http://alvaroalonso.net/

Comment: include your html and css.

Comment: it's not the best idea to post link of your website. Always try to narrow down the problem as much as possible. I cannot test it since it's live, but I suggest you to put `width: 100%` to `html, body` tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the width 1300px to 100%.

```
.nosotros .wrapper {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the fixed width of this div:

```
.nosotros .wrapper {
    width: 1300px;
}
```

Which instead should be set to 100%.